# plotly graph in shiny losses register event on small screens

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Following the info presented on [this page](https://plotly-r.com/linking-views-with-shiny), I made a plotly that uses `event_register("plotly_selecting")` to listen to a click on a data point and do some stuff with that.

The following app does that. It works just fine:

```r
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  verbatimTextOutput("click")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  nms <- row.names(mtcars)
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    p <- plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt, customdata = nms)
    
    p %>% 
      layout(dragmode = "select") %>%
      event_register("plotly_selecting")
  })
  
  output$click <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_click")
    if (is.null(d)) "Click events appear here (double-click to clear)" else d
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I published my app on shinyapps.io. Then I wanted to see how it looked on my smartphone. And I saw that, apparently, the click does not get registered on small screens. You can see that the app above works fine on a desktop screen: you click on a data point and the event get registered.

But if you change to a smartphone screen through DevTools you see that this feature gets lost, as in the following image:

[image]

**So, how do I keep the `plotly::event_data` and/or `plotly::event_register` working on small screens?**

Comment: This is a [known](https://github.com/plotly/angular-plotly.js/issues/143) [issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1858) with plotly.js, it might work in some browsers (Chrome, but not FF/Safari?). They're looking for a $40K sponsorship to implement this ;-)

Comment: The plotly.js issue linked above (#1858) is very old, its status has not been updated while most of the basic interactions are now fully implemented (and the angular-plotly.js issue is out of topic, plotly.R doesn't use angular-plotly).

Comment: This [PR](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/pull/6724) I made a few month ago should solve your issue, it was merged into plotly.js as of [v2.26.2](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/releases/tag/v2.26.2), but the thing is that the latest [plotly.R still uses plotly.js v2.11.1](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/blob/v4.10.4/R/plotly.R#L479-L488) which is almost 2 years old.. I guess the best thing to do is to create a plotly.R issue requesting an update of the plotly.js dependency.

Comment: @EricLavault Is there a hackier way to link the v2.26.2 version to plotly.R? My app is fairly complex and is almost ready, this is the only feature that's missing.

Comment: I would try to replace the [plotly.js bundle included in the plotly.R library](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/blob/master/inst/htmlwidgets/lib/plotlyjs/plotly-latest.min.js) installed on your machine by [one from a release >= v2.26.2](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/v2.26.2/dist/plotly.min.js) (renamed "plotly-latest.min.js") and see if everything works fine. Ideally you have a clone of the R repo so that you can run tests with the new bundle before altering the plotly.R package in your environment(s). Sorry I don't use R at all so I can't test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the bug is due to an old version of `plotly.js` in the `plotly` library.

A quick hacky fix is to manually update the dependency to a more recent version of `plotly.js` (*N.B.* this come w/o any warranty as switching the underlying library may have unforeseen consequences)

```r
library(here)
library(htmltools)

## download the newest evrsion of plotly
lnk <- "https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.27.0.min.js"
dest_dir <- here("www")
dest_fn <- file.path(dest_dir, basename(lnk))

if (!file.exists(dest_fn)) {
  if (!dir.exists(dest_dir)) {
    dir.create(dest_dir)
  }
  download.file(lnk, dest_fn)
}

## switch dependency to newer version

# [...]
output$plot <- renderPlotly({
  p <- plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~ mpg, y = ~ wt, customdata = nms, 
               type = "scatter", mode = "markers")
  ## if you do not like using internal functions look for `plotly-main` in the deps
  idx <- plotly:::plotlyjsBundleIDX(p)
  p$dependencies[[idx]] <- htmlDependency("plotly-main",
                                          gsub("^\\D+((\\d+\\.?)+)\\..*$", "\\1", lnk),
                                          src = here("www"),
                                          script = basename(lnk))
  p %>% 
    layout(dragmode = "select") %>%
    event_register("plotly_selecting") 
})
```

Comment: Thanks @thothal. I accepted your answer because its solves this problem. Unfortunately, in my actual case, it doesn't work. I made this `plot_ly` trying to simplify to a minimal reprex,, but in my case the plot is a map, and apparently the bundle change does not fix the issue in maps. I will try to submit a new question with the specific problem; hopefully you can help me further.